# C#: How do I change the chart control's back color on a form?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, charts

I placed a ChartControl in my Windows Form Application. The form's background is dark grey. I want the chart area the same color as the form background (or transparent) so only the series' color shows. How is this done?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll have better luck and your question won't be downvoted if you show what you've already tried.  The best questions have code, what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the properties of Chart control, there is a property **ChartAreas**. It is collection. If you click on the button next to it, you will get all the options to format the Chart area. If you change Back Color property to **Transparent** here, it will do the trick for you.
For Legend also there is a property of same type called **Legends**.